# How to apply action in HTML for specific logged in user through Spring-boot

Tags: java, html, spring-boot

I am facing a problem where when I perform an action in a particular user logged in and it's getting applied to all other users.
The action getting performed is a click of a button that gets disabled for a particular time. But when we switch the logged-in user, then the changes also appear in that user.

Here is the HTML code

```
<button id="upside" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Up</button>
<button id="downside" onclick="down()" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Down</button>
```

Here is the spring/java code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method ={RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
public ModelAndView GoesUp(@AuthenticationPrincipal CustomUserDetails currentuser) throws IOException {
    if (isAuthenticated()) {       //isAuthenticated is function which check whether the user is logedin or not
    int x=currentuser.getBalance() +10;   //Balance is points available for that user to which we add 10
    currentuser.setBalance(x);
    repo.setUserInfoById(x,currentuser.getId()); // repo is a repository which modify changes in  database1
    repoofdata.setDataInfoById(x,currentuser.getId()); // repoofdata is a repository which modify changes in  database2
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:"+"/app1"); 
     }
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:"+"/signin"); // ( /signin ) is signing page.
}
```

Here is isAuthenticated() function -

```
private boolean isAuthenticated() {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (authentication == null || AnonymousAuthenticationToken.class.
      isAssignableFrom(authentication.getClass())) {
        return false;
    }
    return authentication.isAuthenticated();
}
```

Comment: Please share code for `isAuthenticated` method. Are you sure this method is working properly?

Comment: @mahfujasif Please check the edited question.

Comment: Yes, it works properly for signin page authentication but not working on the HTML page as I have write-in question above.
Can you solve this problem?

Comment: i am still not sure about your requirements. Also i think the problem might be in your jsp files for /app1 and /signin

Comment: can I add if condition of isauthneticated()  in HTML using thymeleaf to authenticate the specific user for button if possible please tell me in the answer box sir

Comment: @mahfujasif app1 is the file in which the HTML of a button is written and /signin is the signing form that has to be displayed if a user is not authenticated